# Not able to update table in asp.net using add parameters

Tags: c#

I am trying to update table patient using the patientId in mysql from asp.net.By using the debugger I am able to see that the execute query for update is not getting executed. May be there is a problem with the syntax of add parameters for update.I will be extremely grateful if someone can find the solution for it.

The function in service class to update patient record:

```
 public bool UpdatePatient(AppointmentInfo appointmentInfo)
    {
        bool set = false;
        conn.GetConnection();
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = conn.GetCommand(Queries.UpdatePatient);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientId", Convert.ToInt32(appointmentInfo.patientId));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", Convert.ToString(appointmentInfo.fName));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mName", Convert.ToString(appointmentInfo.mName));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", Convert.ToString(appointmentInfo.lName));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", Convert.ToInt32(appointmentInfo.age));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", Convert.ToString(appointmentInfo.gender));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", Convert.ToString(appointmentInfo.address));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailId", Convert.ToString(appointmentInfo.emailId));
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()>0) 
            {
                set = true;
            }
            else
            {
                set = false;
            }

        }
        catch (MySqlException)
        {
            set = false;
        }
        conn.CloseConnection();
        return set;
    }
```

Here Queries is a .resx file where I am writing the update query.The query is

```
update patient set fName=@fName,mName=@mName,lName=@lName, 
age=@age,gender=@gender,address=@address,emailId=@emailId,
where patientId=@patientId
```

Here is the model class appointmentInfo

```
 public class AppointmentInfo
{
    public int appointmentId { get; set;}
    public int patientId { get; set; }
    public string dName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide the first name")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First Name cannot be longer than 50 characters and less than 1 character")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use alphabets only please")]
    public string fName { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use alphabets only please")]
    public string mName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide the last name")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Last Name cannot be longer than 50 characters and less than 1 character")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use alphabets only please")]
    public string lName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Enter an age between 1 and 100")]
    public int age { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide the gender")]
    public string gender { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mobile Number is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{10})$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter proper contact details.")]
    public string phNo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide the address")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Address cannot be longer than 50 characters and less than 10 characters")]
    public string address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The email Id is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string emailId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an option")]
    public int specialityId { get; set; }
    public string specialityName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an option")]
    public int doctorId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide the date and time")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime dtTime { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<SpecialityInfo> specialityCollection { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<DoctorInfo> doctorCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You have a comma after the last set. Probably a typo or is it really in your query? By the way. Catching an exception and doing nothing with it is really a pain when you want to debug your problems

Comment: `emailId=@emailId,`, note the extra comma.  You should log the exception information instead of silently throwing away **useful** error information.

Comment: Also it is not clear how do you associate the command with the connection and even if you open or not that connection. Again, better remove that try/catch and let the exception shows its error message (It  is your problem)

Comment: That comma is a typo over here. In the query it is not there.@Amy,@Steve

Comment: Is the method of using the add parameters for the update function is right?I have a doubt over there.

Comment: If the return value of ExecuteNonQuery is zero (and no exception is thrown) then there is only one possibility. You don't have a patient with the patientID passed in the database pointed by the connectionstring used by your code.

Comment: There was a problem with a field.One field was showing null.SO, I have resolved that.thanks a lot for the suggestions.